# Ngnix forward url from first server to second

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have two servers.

Server 1: `185.185.xxx.xxx` (this is the main server with domain mydomain.com)

Server 2: `176.28.xxx.xxx`

On the first server I added A zone

```
A   cdn    176.28.xxx.xxx
```

When I type `cdn.mydomain.com` this link will open `176.28.xxx.xxx` (I'm already set host)
And this is working fine.

**WHAT I NEED**

When user type `mydomain.com/cdn` I need to open same as `cdn.mydomain.com` (on second server)

example

user type: `mydomain.com/cdn/myphotos.zip`

need to open:  `cdn.mydomain.com/myphotos.zip`

**How to set this?**

I'm trying, but no luck. I'm have Ubuntu and Nginx. No Apache.
I'm need config for ngnix. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map to capture the path relative to the cdn directory on Server 1 then define a variable that points to the same file at the root of Server 2.

Maps are evaluated early in the nginx cycle and are a good place to use regular expressions.

```
map $uri $cdn_uri {
    ~^/cdn/(?<path>.+) $scheme://cdn.mydomain.com/$path;
}
```

If the `$cdn_uri` variable is set, redirect to it on Server 2.

```
server {
    # Server 1

    if ($cdn_uri) {
        return 301 $cdn_uri;
    }
}
```